# Access method from user defined package in java

Tags: java, methods, package

Here is my package arithmatic inside which a file called arith.java

```
package arithmatic;

 public class arith{

     public int add(int a, int b){
     return(a+b);
     }
}
```

and outside the arithmatic package a file packagedemo.java

```
import arithmatic.*;
public class packagedemo{

public void disp(int a, int b){

    System.out.println("Addition is : "+ add(a, b));
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    packagedemo pd=new packagedemo();
    pd.disp(20,10);
}
}
```

after compiling it gives me error as,

```
packagedemo.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(int,int)
location: class packagedemo
            System.out.println("Addition is : "+ add(a, b));
```

I really dont understand why this error occurs any solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply importing a class, you cannot directly access a class member method like this

```
add(a, b)
```

You first need to create and instance of your `arith` class and then call `add` method using that instance. Something like this:

```
public void disp(int a, int b){

    arith arithObj = new arith();
    System.out.println("Addition is : "+ arithObj.add(a, b));
}
```

Comment: now it is saying,     packagedemo.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class artih
location: class packagedemo
                artih ar=new arith();
                ^

Comment: @Darpan just make sure the class names and package imports are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instance of `arith`  since  the method `add` is an insntance member of that class.

```
public void disp(int a, int b){
    Arith art= new Arith();
    System.out.println("Addition is : "+ art.add(a, b));
}
```

As a side note please follow java naming conventions ,Class name starts with capital letter.

```
public class Arith{
```

I guess you are checking the package level accesses, in that case you are looking for `protected` modifier for your `add()`  method. So when you create instance of `Arith` insntance in other packages you won't have access to that protected member. Now it is public so, you can use it.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA class name is sadly starting with small case arith and not Arith :-)

Comment: I saw OP declared class `arith`, so I corrected it as I cannot do the same mistake again :)

Comment: No still in the code you have provided it is     Arith art= new Arith();

Comment: I provided the code with that correction. Not used the same code given by OP.